# What is a word that means "Psychadelic Nightmare"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I read a word that was used to describe the original Willy Wonka movie's bad acid trip boat scene, the definition of the word was something like a circus of hallucinogenic nightmares and the word sounded like "cacophony".
I think it started with the letter 'P' and the word is definitely an adjective.

Please help! Trying to find this word is driving me insane.

Comment: ["Too much Welsh rarebit"](https://www.thesmartset.com/article06031302/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phantasmagoric;

[Phantasmagoria](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phantasmagoria)
  " an exhibition of illusions "

Answer (score 0):

Using [RhymeZone](https://www.rhymezone.com/) may help; it's a synonym generator specifically for rhymes, half-rhymes, and near-rhymes. Since the sound of the word is critical for identifying it.

Additionally, besides "psychedelic" itself, these seemed closest to me:

> [psychotropic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/psychotropic?s=t) - adj - "affecting mental activity, behavior, or perception, as a mood-altering drug"
>
> [psychoactive](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/psychoactive) - adj - "of or relating to a substance having a profound or significant effect on mental processes"

Edit, adding:

> [psychosis](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/psychosis?s=t) - pl noun - "a mental disorder characterized by symptoms, such as delusions or hallucinations, that indicate impaired contact with reality"

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

***kaleidoscope ...kaleidoscopic***

See definition 2:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kaleidoscope)

> 1)  an instrument containing loose bits of colored material (such as glass or plastic) between two flat plates and two plane mirrors so placed that changes of position of the bits of material are reflected in an endless variety of patterns

**2) : something resembling a kaleidoscope: such as
a : a variegated changing pattern or scene a kaleidoscope of colors**

"*cacophony*"
 refers to sound, and is more or less the audio equivalent of ***kaleidoscope***.

They alliterate; so maybe "cacophony" stuck in your mind.

Comment: "...and the word sounded like "cacophony". I think it started with the letter 'P'" is confusing. Do you mean it starts with the letter"P" but sounds like /k/?

Comment: Kaleidoscope is very close to the feel of the word, strange visuals are involved. Thank you